# Make this effect in a glass shader, normal map or displacement?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, displacement

I want to make this kind of effect in a glass bottle of wine, but i dont know what would be the best approach for making this.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome, thanks for the question.  Can you describe exactly what it is you want to replicate?  You can use the edit link at the bottom of your question to add details.

Comment: Have you tried sculpting to add the irregularities to get that sort of rough effect?

Comment: Hello Allen, Sure, I would like to add a logo and kind of "embossed" if it is that the actual term to displace in the model of the bottle, but I have doubts of how it would be the right approach

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go the displacement route. You can achieve what you're looking for rather easily by mixing a couple of Noise Textures - one "Large" and less detailed one for the warped shape of the bottle, and another "Smaller", more detailed one for the little surface bumps. I inverted the mix and darkened it a little to make the roughness of the Material as well. I mixed the result with white before the displacement to soften the effect and make it more realistic (default "contrast" is often too strong).

[image: Warp1]

Result in Cycles (denoised):

[image: Warp2]

If you're willing to subdivide your model quite a bit (using a subsurf modifier), you can enable true displacement to make the whole bottle warp (shown below with exaggerated effect - 0.4 displacement scale) - make sure to switch to "displacement and bump" or "displacement only" in the material settings (only works in Cycles):

[image: Warp3]